Extract data from multiple sheets
I have multiple source sheets "DATA01", "DATA02", "DATA03", "データ" (one sheet name is in Japanese. I don't know if error has anything to do with the different language).
I modified code from an answer I received to a previous question: Extract data from multiple sheets into one sheet using array VBA
Conditions:

if column 1 has value And column 5 is not equal to 1 then copy that row
if column 2 has value And column 5 is not equal to 1 then copy that row
if column 4 has value And column 5 is not equal to 1 And if either today's date is in between column 13 & 14 value OR value of column 14 is less or equal to today then copy that row
if column 3 has value And either column 4 has value or not And column 5 is not equal to 1 And column 13 has no value then copy that row

The modified code does not work for the sheet that is named in Japanese.
I have slightly modified code in the step where data IsToBeCopied:
Function IsToBeCopied(Data As Variant, srcRow As Long) As Boolean

If Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,1) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5))<>"1" then
    IsToBeCopied = True 
Elseif Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,2) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5))<>"1" then
    IsToBeCopied = True
Elseif Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,4)) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5))<>"1" and _
    (Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,14)) And ((Data(srcRow,13)<= date And Data(srcRow,14)>=date) or _
    Data(srcRow,14) <= Date)) then
    IsToBeCopied = True
Elseif Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,3)) And (Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,4)) or IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,4))) And_
    CStr(Data(srcRow,5)) <> "1" And IsEmpty(Data(srcRow,13)) Then
    IsToBeCopied = True
end if
end function


Try out this code, I corrected some syntax & logic errors.
Function IsToBeCopied(Data As Variant, srcRow As Long) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = False
    
    If Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 1)) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5)) <> "1" Then
        result = True
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 2)) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5)) <> "1" Then
        result = True
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 4)) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5)) <> "1" And _
           ((Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 13)) And Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 14)) And Data(srcRow, 13) <= Date And Data(srcRow, 14) >= Date) Or _
           (Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 14)) And Data(srcRow, 14) <= Date)) Then
        result = True
    ElseIf Not IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 3)) And CStr(Data(srcRow, 5)) <> "1" And IsEmpty(Data(srcRow, 13)) Then
        result = True
    End If
    
    IsToBeCopied = result
End Function

